# Append HTML and Text into a LI

Tags: jquery

How can I append a blurb of text into my first `LI`s'

```
  <ul id="topnav">
    <li class="mainNavFirst"><a href="/solutions">Solution</a>
    <li class="mainNavLast"><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
```

I want to append text inside

```
<li class="mainNavFirst"><a href="/solutions">Solution <span>Blurb Goes Here</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the specific use case for [**`.append()`**](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$('.mainNavFirst a:first-child').append('<span>Blurb Goes Here</span>');
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/kPxcH/)

Specific example from jQuery Docs.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me and I like it because its short and minimal. However, Lets say i want to put the span tag INSIDE the First `a` tag?

Comment: just changed the selector to append to the `a` tag inside `.mainNavFirst`

Comment: This appends it to all `a` tags that are nested underneath `.mainNavFirst` - i just want the first `a` tag in that LI to be appended.. is that clear enough?

Comment: ok, didn't get that from the original question, updated again to only select the first one.

Comment: it still adds the `span` tag to all the other `a` tags inside the `.mainNavFirst` - but don't worry this is fair enough..i appreciate the assistance @jon

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.mainNavFirst').html($('.mainNavFirst').html()+" <span>Blurb Goes Here</span>")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li a','#topnav').eq(0).append('<span>Blurb</span>');
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#topnav li:first > a').append(' <span>Blurb Goes Here</span>');
```

Answer (score -1):

Then try this :

```
$(".mainNavFirst").append("<a href='/solutions'>Solution <span>Blurb Goes Here</span></a>");
```